# What can I do to make my webapp auto refresh? Pages won't load in sequence. IOS

Tags: android, ios

I made an app using WP and apppresser. Finally got the sliders and everything working.  BUT....
my popup windows work nicely using this code. but, when i hit the "done" button (on IOS. Works fine on android) it wont work again until I refresh the page (kinda a pain) by switching between  my home panes.

Help?  Everything has a different "btnNUMBERClick" name

```
<!--Pay Water Bill-->


<a href  onclick="Btn777Click()"><img src="http://pwpllc.net/apppress3/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/maps105new.jpg" width="105"></a>

<script>
var myWindow;

function Btn777Click()
{
Btn777Click = window.open("http://maps-directions.org/15/?keyword=quest%20map%20directions&gclid=CM--_tSo97wCFe87MgodpgEAGA","myWindow","width=200,height=100");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Basically, for some reason, when I click on several of my (pop up, out of app) links in a row...it stops popping up after 1, 2, maybe 3.  and just sits there until i refresh.

Comment: Because I'm moving to a slider design (http://pwpllc.net/apppress3/royalslider/) there won't be a refresh button or way to do it (even if a user understood the situation, which none will)